# SPARQL query for RECIPE selection

Tags: filter, sparql

ok, let's say that I need to extract all those recipes containing 2/3 ingredients.
The recipes are represented as linked data and this is the ontology used http://linkedrecipes.org/schema.
I know how to find recipes with curry:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <htp://ww.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX recipe: <htp://linkedrecipes.org/schema/>

SELECT ?label ?recipe 
WHERE{ 
?food rdfs:label ?label2 . 
?food recipe:ingredient_of ?recipe .
?recipe a recipe:Recipe . 
?recipe rdfs:label ?label.  

FILTER (REGEX(STR(?label2), 'curry', 'i'))
}
```

But how can i find recipes with curry and chicken for example?

Answer (score 1):

This should find curry and chicken:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <htp://ww.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX recipe: <htp://linkedrecipes.org/schema/>

SELECT ?label ?recipe { 
    ?recipe a recipe:Recipe . 
    ?recipe rdfs:label ?label.  

    ?curry recipe:ingredient_of ?recipe .
    ?curry rdfs:label ?curry_label . 
    FILTER (REGEX(STR(?curry_label), 'curry', 'i'))

    ?chicken recipe:ingredient_of ?recipe .
    ?chicken rdfs:label ?chicken_label . 
    FILTER (REGEX(STR(?chicken_label), 'chicken', 'i'))
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked...You just forgot the WHERE statement, but it's fine. Thanks cygry...